# Grant access to a table to all users

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to assign a grant to a table for all users, or a default permission so that when new users are created they will have the specific grants for that table to `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE`?

Answer (score 5):

What I am about to propose would be considered by many to be a hack, but will get you what you want.

**STEP 01 : Create a special database called `specialdata`**

```
CREATE DATABASE specialdata;
```

**STEP 02 : As `root@localhost`, place the table you want into the `specialdata` database**

```
CREATE TABLE specialdata.specialtable LIKE mydb.mytb;
INSERT INTO specialdata.specialtable SELECT * FROM mydb.mytb;
```

**STEP 03 : Create anonymous user access to the `specialdata` database with the needed grants**

```
INSERT INTO mysql.db
SET host='%',user='',db='specialdata',
Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**STEP 04 : There is no STEP 04**

Every user should have access to any table in `specialdata`

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: I think without entry in mysql.user table it should not work. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nice hack! This seems to work well

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL does not support wildcards in user names.

This is from [mysql 5.7 manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html). But you may use a special user (or anonymous user), grant that user the permissions you want everybody to have. And then you could make a separate connection with that user to access the table. Not sure it makes a great sense though. It's perhaps easier to just grant these privileges to new users when creating them.